# Recursively Finding a Max Value in a Vector in Java

Tags: java, recursion, vector, inner-classes

So for a programming class we need to recursively find the value of the maximum and minimum values of a vector. I know how to do this using iteration but can't figure out what I need to do to get this working with recursion which is required for this assignment. I would be able to get the max and min values just using element at if I could get the indexes but everything I've tried so far just gets me tons of errors. Here's all the code I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Lab4<E> {
    Vector <Double> data; 
    public void readData() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        {
            Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the data file name: ");
            String inFile = console.next();
            File fileRef = new File(inFile);
            Scanner tokens = new Scanner(fileRef);
            data = new Vector<Double>();
            while(tokens.hasNext())
                {
                Double value = tokens.nextDouble();
                data.add(value);
                }
            System.out.print("The values in the file are: "+data.toString()+"\n");
            System.out.print("The number of values in the file is: "+(data.size())+"\n");
            tokens.close();
            console.close();
        }
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
            throws IOException
    {
    Lab4 fileTest = new Lab4();
    fileTest.readData();
    System.out.println(obj);
    }

    class MinMaxObject
    {
        private double max, min;
        private int maxPos, minPos;
         public MinMaxObject()
          {
            this.max =Double.MIN_VALUE;
            this.maxPos = 0;
            this.min=Double.MAX_VALUE;
            this.minPos = 0;

         }
         public MinMaxObject(double ma, int maP, double mi, int miP)
         {
            this.max = ma;
            this.maxPos = maP;
            this.min = mi;
            this.minPos = miP;
         }
        public void setMax(double newMax)
        {
            max = newMax;
        }
        public double getMax() {
            return max;
            } 
        public void setMin(double newMin)
        {
            min = newMin;
        }
        public double getMin() {
            return min;
            } 
        public void setMaxPos(int newMaxPos)
        {
            maxPos = newMaxPos;
        }
        public int getMaxPos() {
            return maxPos;
            } 
        public void setMinPos(int newMinPos)
        {
            minPos = newMinPos;
        }
        public int getMinPos() {
            return minPos;
            } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless it is a specific requirement to use `Vector`, *DON'T*, and if it is, tell teacher to update assignment to something newer than 1998. [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) was replaced by [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) back in Java 1.2 in 1998, and javadoc says:

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`.

If synchronization is needed, I'd recommend using [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) around an `ArrayList` over the use of `Vector`, which means that `Vector` should never be used, unless with an old API that requires it.

---

Java doesn't support tail-recursion, but let me explain anyway, since that would be the preferred way in other languages that do support it.

When you use recursion, the function call goes on the call stack. Eventually, with very deep recursion, you may run out of stack space, which will cause a `StackOverflowException` and kill your program.

In pure functional programming, where all variables are immutable, the way to perform a loop, without using up stack space, is to make the recursive call the very last thing in the method. That way, a functional compiler can simply *jump* back to the beginning of the method, without adding to the call stack, which is only possible because there's nothing more to do in the current invocation.

To make that work for a method that must return the maximum value of a list, the recursive call passes in the `List`, the next index to process, and the maximum value found so far. At end of list, it returns the incoming value.

For ease of use, there is often a lead-in method, so caller doesn't have to setup the extra parameters.

```
public static Integer max(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return max(list, 1, list.get(0));
}
private static final Integer max(List<Integer> list, int index, Integer maxSoFar) {
    if (index == list.size())
        return maxSoFar;
    Integer value = list.get(index);
    Integer maxValue = (value.compareTo(maxSoFar) > 0 ? value : maxSoFar);
    return max(list, index + 1, maxValue); // tail-recursive call
}
```

The above code will only perform well on `List` objects with direct access by index, such as `ArrayList`, but will perform badly on lists like `LinkedList`.

For all `List` objects and any other `Collection` object, you can use `Iterator` instead.

Here, I'll also show how to use `Optional`.

```
public static Optional<Integer> max(Iterable<Integer> coll) {
    Iterator<Integer> iter = coll.iterator();
    if (! iter.hasNext())
        return Optional.empty();
    return Optional.of(max(iter, iter.next()));
}
private static final Integer max(Iterator<Integer> iter, Integer maxSoFar) {
    if (! iter.hasNext())
        return maxSoFar;
    Integer value = iter.next();
    return max(iter, (value.compareTo(maxSoFar) > 0 ? value : maxSoFar));
}
```

---

To get both minimum and maximum value at the same time, you need a class for returning the two values.

The code can also be updated to work on anything that is `Comparable`.

```
public static final class MinMax<T> {
    private final T min;
    private final T max;
    MinMax(T min, T max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }
    public T getMin() {
        return this.min;
    }
    public T getMax() {
        return this.max;
    }
}
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> Optional<MinMax<T>> minMax(Iterable<T> coll) {
    Iterator<T> iter = coll.iterator();
    if (! iter.hasNext())
        return Optional.empty();
    T value = iter.next();
    return Optional.of(minMax(iter, value, value));
}
private static final <T extends Comparable<T>> MinMax<T> minMax(Iterator<T> iter, T minSoFar, T maxSoFar) {
    if (! iter.hasNext())
        return new MinMax<>(minSoFar, maxSoFar);
    T value = iter.next();
    return minMax(iter, (value.compareTo(minSoFar) < 0 ? value : minSoFar),
                        (value.compareTo(maxSoFar) > 0 ? value : maxSoFar));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the rundown. I was able to get it working eventually. Yeah he was adamant about us using vectors and every piece of advice on the subject used arraylists.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively get the min of a vector with code like:

```
static double min(Vector<Double> v, int index) {
    if (index == v.size() - 1) {
        return v.get(index);
    }
    double val = min(v, index + 1);

    if (v.get(index) < val) {
        return v.get(index);
    } else {
        return val;
    }
}
```

You can find the max recursively in the same way, just switch the < with a > in the last if statement

Answer (score 0):

Use an auxiliary method which takes an index parameter and your max/min object. The code should be self explanatory:

```
public MinMaxObject getMinMax(Vector<Double> vector) {
    MinMaxObject minMax = new MinMaxObject();
    getMinMaxAux(vector, minMax, 0);
    return minMax;
}

public void getMinMaxAux(Vector<Double> vector, MinMaxObject minMax, int index) {
    if(index < vector.size())
    {
        double value = vector.get(index);
        if(value > minMax.getMax())
        {
            minMax.setMax(value);
            minMax.setMaxPos(index);
        }
        if(value < minMax.getMin())
        {
            minMax.setMin(value);
            minMax.setMinPos(index);
        }
        getMinMaxAux(vector, minMax, index + 1);
    }
}
```

You can also opt to not pass `MinMaxObject` in your parameters and get it from the recursive call. `MinMaxObject` would be created when you reach the end of the vector. But it will produce code that might be somewhat confusing.
It's a good exercise if you want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, my final method ended up looking a lot like this.

Answer (score 0):

But there is direct method in vector to find max  value

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
v.add(new Double("3.0"));
v.add(new Double("4.0"));
Object obj = Collections.max(v);
System.out.println(obj);
```

}
}

Comment: Yeah but for the assignment he required us to do it recursively.